# Find C++ small netcat

Tags: c++, ssh, netcat

I need some stand-alone implementation of netcat.. the problem is netcat needs to add 1000 libs.. i need one small netcat in a single file to change and implement new things..

Someone know a simple-netcat?

Comment: nc is small and standalone already... it may just have a lot of dependencies.  Bite the bullet and get installing!

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat on my machine shows only **one** external dependency (besides libc), and that's only because it's linked with a crypto lib which is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OpenBSD netcat](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/usr.bin/nc/) seems to require just a BSD'ish C library.